# autoscaling in matplotlib, plotting different time series in same chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I have a 'master' panda dataframe that has a time series of 'polarity' values for several terms. I want to work with 4 of them, so I extracted 4 separate dataframes, containing the time series(same time series for all of the terms, but different polarity values.)

I plotted them in 4 separate matplotlib graphs, using the code below

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
polarity_godzilla.plot(ax=axes[0,0]); axes[0,0].set_title('Godzilla')
polarity_henry_kissinger.plot(ax=axes[0,1]); axes[0,1].set_title('Henry Kissinger')
polarity_bmwi.plot(ax=axes[1,0]); axes[1,0].set_title('BMWi')
polarity_duran_duran.plot(ax=axes[1,1]); axes[1,1].set_title('Duran Duran')
```

Now, I want to graph them all in the same graph so I have an idea of the magnitude of each graph, because the auto scaling of matplotlib can give the wrong impression about the magnitude by just looking at the graphs.
[image]

Two questions:
1) Is there are way to set the min and max values of the Y-axis when plotting? 
2) I am not an expert in matplotlib, so I am not sure how to plot the 4 variables in the same graph using different colors, markers, labels, etc. I tried nrows = 1, ncols = 1 but can't plot anything.

Thank you

Comment: did you check the approach of the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axes[i,j].set_ylim([min,max], auto=False)` will set the y-limits of the plot in the `i,j`th plot. `auto=False` keeps it from clobbering your settings.

You can plot multiple lines on the same graph by calling `plt.hold(True)`, drawing a bunch of plots, and then calling `plt.show()` or `plt.savefig(filename)`.

You can pass a color code into `plt.plot()` as a third positional argument. The syntax is a little byzantine (it's inherited from MATLAB); it's documented in the [matplotlib.pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot) documentation. You can pass this argument to `DataFrame.plot` as (for example) `style='k--'`.

For your case, I would try

```
fig, ax = plt.axes()
plt.hold(True)
polarity_godzilla.plot(ax=ax, style="k-o", label="Godzilla")
polarity_henry_kissinger(ax=ax, style="b-*", label="Kissinger")
#etc.
plt.legend()  #to draw a legend with the labels you provided
plt.show() #or plt.savefig(filename)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps loop into your `AxesSubplot` objects and call `autoscale` passing the `axis` parameter:

```
for ax in axes:
    ax.autoscale(axis='y')
```

Comment: Thank you! A combination/hybrid of the two suggestions worked for me. Thank you.